# html_data for initial data and json_data for AJAX data in jstree

Tags: jstree

Can I configure jstree to use the html_data plugin to load the initial data and the json_data plugin to process subsequent AJAX data?  Thanks!

Comment: The first 'load' is via ajax too or static?

Comment: It could be either.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first load data could be static then you simply use static json to load the first tree and then ajax to reload it.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  My preference is to keep all of client-side scripts in their own files, but this required either putting a server-generated script tag in the view code (I'm using ASP.NET MVC) or putting JSON in an HTML tag.  I did the former, though I find the server-side code mixed with JavaScript hard to read.  I also could have loaded the entire tree using AJAX, which might have been the cleaner approach.

I'll take your suggested answer to imply that no, I cannot configure jstree to do what I asked.  I appreciate the reply!